# Rendering Problem with AMD

Tags: rendering, animation

I´ve got a Problem with the rendering with my GPU (AMD Readon R9 280x) it is not the result compared to the CPU (Intel I7)

The 2 Pictures show the difference.

What can i do?

CPU renderd:

[image]

GPU rendered:

[image]

Comment: there is a long list of issues with AMDs R9 cards see if any of the following posts help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=r9+